# robustbase can't be installed causing caret issue

Tags: r, r-caret, install.packages

I’m trying to install caret on my mac.  I’m running mac os siera.  When I run

```
library(‘caret’)
```

it throws an error because it says ‘robustbase’ isn’t installed, so I try running the code below to install robustbase and I get the error below.

I’ve found a couple posts that mention setting dependencies=TRUE but I’ve tried that, and accomplished nothing.  Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Error:

```
install.packages('robustbase',dependencies=TRUE)

  There is a binary version available but the source version
  is later:
             binary source needs_compilation
robustbase 0.93-1.1 0.93-3              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?
y/n: y
installing the source package ‘robustbase’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/robustbase_0.93-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2960261 bytes (2.8 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.8 MB

* installing *source* package ‘robustbase’ ...
** package ‘robustbase’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c R-rng4ftn.c -o R-rng4ftn.o
gfortran   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c eigen.f -o eigen.o
make: gfortran: No such file or directory
make: *** [eigen.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘robustbase’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/robustbase’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘robustbase’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/l6/22422fbd22bcctgfsyx22_rw0000gp/T/RtmpZQRb5t/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: When it asks you if you want to install from sources, just say "no"

Comment: @MrFlick THANK YOU, that did it.  Installed caret afterwards and it loads fine too now.